# Integrate colorbox into flexslider

Tags: jquery

I have a flexslider carousel and I'd like to add the functionality that when you click an item in the carousel it opens up in a lighbox (I'm using colorbox). How do you properly implement it? BTW, the code below loads the colorbox properly when I take the `<ul>` section outside of the flexslider div. Here's what I'm trying:

Head:

```
<!--jquery-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--flexslider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<!--colorbox-->
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" type="text/css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.gallery').colorbox();
});
</script>
```

Body:

```
<div id="flexslider" class="flexslider">
<ul>
   <li><a href="images/img01.jpg" class="gallery"><img src="images/img01.jpg" /></a></li>;
   <li><a href="images/img02.jpg" class="gallery"><img src="images/img02.jpg" /></a></li>;
   <li><a href="images/img03.jpg" class="gallery"><img src="images/img03.jpg" /></a></li>;
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need a brief timeout function to allow everything to load properly.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function () { //necessary to add a brief pause for colorbox to reintiate
           startColorbox();
        }, 500);
        function startColorbox() {
           $('a.gallery').colorbox();       
        }
    });
</script>
```